# Thymeleaf - Image to act as Hyperlink

Tags: image, hyperlink, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf, how can I make an image act as a hyperlink?

The [Thymeleaf Documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) says nothing about images and I tried using standard HTML for this issue but none of the below attempts made my image an active hyperlink.

```
<a th:href="@{/user/myUser}">
    <img src="../../static/images/image.jpg" alt="logo"/>
</a>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <img src="../../static/images/image.jpg" alt="logo"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Those are both correct. There is something else wrong unrelated to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <a href="/oauth2/authorization/google">
            <img alt="Google Login" title="Google login"
                th:src="@{/images/login-with-google.png}" />
        </a>
```